# Dereferencing a set iterator causes a seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to determine why the following code is throwing a segfault on line 10 (where we dereference `upgradeIter`).

```
bool UpgradeType::isAffected(const UnitType *unitType) const{
    if(std::find(effects.begin(), effects.end(), unitType)!=effects.end()) return true;

    // Check if the unit has any of the affected tags
    std::set<string>::iterator upgradeIter;
    for(upgradeIter = tags.begin(); upgradeIter != tags.end(); ++upgradeIter) {
        std::set<string>::iterator unitIter;
        for(unitIter = unitType->getTags().begin(); unitIter != unitType->getTags().end(); ++unitIter) {
            string unitTag = *unitIter;
            string upgradeTag = *upgradeIter;
            if(unitTag == upgradeTag) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The context is that `UpgradeType` has "tags" (just a set of strings). Units also have tags. If a unit shares at least one tag with the upgrade, then the unit is affected by the upgrade.

I don't see any reason why the mentioned line would crash. It seems to me that there is no circumstances under which the iterator could be invalid.

In other parts of the code that display the contents of `tags` (used in very similar ways), the output is as expected.

EDIT: I've just found out that `unitType->getTags().size()` is 0. So I don't understand why the body of the for loop is even executed. `unitIter != unitType->getTags().end()`, however, is evaluating to true. This seems off.

Comment: There could be a gazillion reasons, not necessarily related to sets and their iterators per se. Perhaps your string was already destroyed together with the entire `tags` set. Try inserting diagnostic output, or looking at the variables in the debugger.

Comment: @n.m., but `tags` is a field of a `UpgradeType` instance which is never destroyed until the game is done. As far as I know, the members of the vector won't be destroyed until the vector is.

Comment: The fact is thst the program crashes. This means some of your asumptions about its behaviour are not valid. Validate everything with independent checks.

Comment: You have correct copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators in your classes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, which classes? `UpgradeType` and `UnitType` do not (they don't create copies or assign anywhere, and have no destructors).

Comment: So you never ever anywhere pass or return any of those structures by value? Then you should not have to worry about that.

Comment: What is the return type of `getTags()` ? If it returns a container by value then that loop will go horribly wrong.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I'm actually not sure. It returns a field directly, eg: `class MyClass { std::set<string> tags; public: std::set<string> getTags() { return tags; } };`.

Comment: I have not found a solution to this problem. The work around that I've used was to add `if(!unitType->getTags().empty()) return false;` before the for loop. I don't understand why this is needed, though. It seems to me that the inner for loop should be skipped if the size is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this with the help of Yggdrasil [on this site](https://forum.megaglest.org/index.php?topic=9543.msg90914#msg90914) (which also means that Matt McNabb in the question's comments was correct). Quoting his post below:

> As someone more or less mentioned on stackoverflow: Change getTags() to return a reference, not a value/copy.
>
> `const set &getTags() const {return tags;}`
>
> Be aware that the return type is const, so use a const iterator.
>
> Not sure if that's all, but you don't want a (deep) copy there, for sure. The iterator gets out of bounds because you check against the end of a different set. Every call to getTags() gets its own copy.